# Pandas dataframe, max value where column value is greater than variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get the name back from a dataframe based on if the cost of a product is less than the amount I have to spend. This is my dataframe with a list of products and their prices.

[image: Dataframe example]

I've tried:

```
def shopping(cash):
    x = df.loc[df['Cost'] <= cash, 'Name'].max()
    return x
```

But it's just returning nothing, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please submit your full workflow? Your code looks fine to me - we can't debug your code without knowing the context of how it's called. Read the guide to creating a full [mre]. Also, please post all data, errors, and code as [formatted code blocks](//help/formatting) not as images. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before running your function make sure that values in `df['cash']` are of a number type (such as int or float).

```
df['Cost'] = df['Cost'].astype(float)
```

Why are you applying a max on the `name` column? What do you mean by maximum name? I would suggest removing `max()` if you want the name of all such products.

Comment: I was trying to get back the most expensive item, so only really wanted the max value of that dataframe once it was filtered on the amount I have to spend

Comment: Hi there - welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guide to [answer]. Your answer is dangerously close to being more of a comment than an answer - just be aware that asking for clarification and providing tips without providing an answer to the OP's question are not allowed as answers. I know you don't have enough rep yet to comment, but there are plenty of other (clear) questions out there that you could take a stab at to get the required [50 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) for commenting.

Comment: @AndyMcCammont if you're trying to find the *name* corresponding to the maximum *value* you'll need to do something more complex, e.g. `df.loc[df.Cost.idxmax(), 'Name']`. `df.Name.max()` will return the Name with the highest string value (e.g. z > a, za > bza, a > ZZZ, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this code-
If you spend $12 cash then you are checking for item which is close to $12 which can be bought.
I think you forget running function `shopping` so output is not getting.Run the below code.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [['banana', 10], ['tomato', 15], ['apple', 20]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Cost'])
  
# print dataframe.
df

def shopping(cash):
    x = df.loc[df['Cost'] <= cash, 'Name'].max()
    return x
shopping(12)
```

Output-

```
banana
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I was running the function in my own code but even after copying in your code to PyCharm i'm getting no output. Is there something else I might be missing as a simple system requirement?

Comment: pls try changing your ide to https://colab.research.google.com/?utm_source=scs-index

It worked fine in colab notebook which I am using.